# Python Beautiful soup how to find li in ul?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
for i in soup.find("ul",attrs={"class":"clearfix"}):
     for durum in i.find_all('li'):
         print(durum)
```

I want to take `li` in `ul` with BeautifulSoup so I write this command but I get an error
`'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'`.

What went wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please take a minute to read [ask]

Comment: `soup.find` returns a single element (the string of the tag), not an iterable list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

You try to iterate the result of `soup.find("ul",attrs={"class":"clearfix"})` but it is not iterable cause `find()` wont give you a `list` it always provides the `NavigableString`

### So how to fix that?

Use `find_all()` instead:

```
for i in soup.find_all("ul",attrs={"class":"clearfix"}):
```

Or

```
for durum in soup.find("ul",attrs={"class":"clearfix"}).find_all('li'):
    print(durum)
```

Or

```
for durum in soup.select('ul.clearfix li'):
    print(durum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python says that you are calling find_all method to an `NavigableString` object. This object doesn't have this method defined.

Check official documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start

On Quick start there's an example that will be fine for you.

Look to `find` definition: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

It only return one result.

`find_all` for iterate to all items  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all